# Strange looking characters printed on the DOS console

Tags: dos

I am writing a simple DOS utility that uses the findstr utility to search for certain phrases in a HTML log file. Whenever findstr finds a match, it will print the match on the console. I am seeing strange characters printed on the console that look something like:

```
.á374.á.á0.á.áif.ácity.á=.á"94606.á.á.á.á.á
```

Any idea what might be going on? Is there a switch in findstr that I should be using?

Comment: What do you expect it to print? The repeating part `.á` doesn't look like utf8 or any other encoding I'm familiar with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your HTML log file probably contains UTF-8 encoded data, but `findstr` (or your console) doesn't support UTF-8 output and is trying to interpret everything in Latin-1.

Comment: I see. Is there a DOS utility I can use that can search in UTF-8 encoded data (or possibly encode the document in ASCII)?

Comment: UTF-8 is compatible with ACSII. So any ASCII char is already a valid UTF-8 char. I've heard good things about PowerGREP for Windows, but never used it.